# net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy

Tags: java, json

I want to write the value of list in JSON File. But it's giving an exception.

```
JSONArray objJsonArray = null;
FileWriter objJsonFileWriter = null;
try {
  objJsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(objList); //<- This line is giving net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy
  objJsonFileWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\MyJson.json");
  objJsonFileWriter.write(objJsonArray.toString());
  objJsonFileWriter.flush();
  objJsonFileWriter.close();
} catch (JSONException jse) {
  jse.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please make me know how to get rid of this exception. I am doing this work using core Java

Comment: provide the sample data which is there in objList

Comment: I am getting objList as a parameter. It consists of multiple values from DB. Ok Giving you.

Comment: You have a reference cycle. Some object has an instance variable pointing to another object, which has an instance variable pointing back at the first object. Possibly a longer chain (a -> b -> c -> a, etc.)

Comment: SO what should I do in that case @Kevin

Comment: objList consist of values which is fetched from database. It consist of Multiple rows and columns. I am getting values from DB using Hibernet.

Comment: Figure out where the reference is and how you want to break it. You probably want to use an object ID somewhere instead of the full object.

Comment: List<PlayerMaster> objList (this is the reference) consist of data of multiple fields and multiple column. Now can you tell me how to break it. if I do to get value by loop e.g. for(PlayerMaster xyz:objList){ System.out.println(xyz.getFirstName) } This gives result.

Comment: But one of my friend told me to just do this, objJsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(objList); simply pass objList and it will work. But it's giving exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Kevin for your valuable suggestion.

```
JSONArray objJsonArray = null;
    FileWriter objJsonFileWriter = null;
    PlayerMasterJsonInfoBean objBean = null;

    try {
      objList.setFirst_name(getPlayerMaster.getFirst_name()); //<- Get the value from bean class then add to collection class
      objList.setLast_name(getPlayerMaster.getLast_name()); //<- Get the value from bean class then add to collection class
      objJsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(objList); //<- Then pass object here
      objJsonFileWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\MyJson.json");
      objJsonFileWriter.write(objJsonArray.toString());
      objJsonFileWriter.flush();
      objJsonFileWriter.close();
    } catch (JSONException jse) {
      jse.printStackTrace();
    }
```